# Reload jqgrid but also reload the select list which is dynamically loaded through ajax in add/edit modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid

in title i have mention what im tryin' to achieve, here is the code i'm working with

i have `colModel`

```
....
editoptions:{value:getNames()}
....

function getNames() {
    var Names = $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/GetNames',
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    return Names;
}
```

Now when i fire `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");` the grid is getting reloaded but the 
Action `GetNames` is not geting called, so the select list on my add/edit modal is not filling up the latest data coming from server..

Im using jquery ui tabs, 2 tabs each tab reders a jqgrid, so let say in 1st tab i add a Name, now on 2nd tab when im adding Contact i show Names in the select list, since both the grid are loaded once, im tryin' to reload the tab on demand, now grid getting reloaded but the script function which's makes ajax request to get Names is not getting hit...

**Note**: things are working fine for the 1st load when page is loaded, ie my select list is getting populated if i refresh the page after i added Names on my 1st tab..